# Why can’t I install a new sound card onto my motherboard?

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, motherboard

I have bought a ASUS XONAR SE 5.1 sound card (PCIe) and tried installing it into multiple slots in my computer which has an ASUS Z97-C motherboard and running Windows 7 Pro.

I've tried inserting the card into several slots and after rebooting the card did not show up. I've removed the card from the motherboard and took a look at my device manager and saw under "other devices an unknown device" with hardware ID of "pnp0a0a". I could find some drivers on Google but none of them worked and I don't know if this has something to do with the fact the the computer does not recognize the sound card or not.

Not sure what to do next. Any help will be appreciated.

**Strange update:**

After trying to stick the sound card into PCIe slot 1 again, I've checked the device manager and saw this:

[image]

Not sure how this makes sense but this is not a sound card.

Comment: Did you install the required [software](https://www.asus.com/us/Sound-Cards/Xonar-SE/HelpDesk_Download/)?

Comment: For the sound card? Yes. When loading it, it does not recognize a card.

Comment: pnp0a0a is not the device ID for the sound card.  It is the device ID for stuff ASUS uses to communicate with UEFI (wrongly aka bios) from windows.  This implies to me that you didn't install the motherboard drivers.  I myself ALSO WOULD NOT INSTALL these drivers unless I absolutely had to.  They *should be* unneeded anyways but *might* be needed by windows to enable the slot but I doubt it.  Use [these instructions](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enter-uefi-bios-windows-10-pcs) to get to your UEFI firmware settings or hit the [del] key on boot.  Play around in there to enable the slot.

Comment: Is there a card in PCI-EX16 Port 2?
And/or is this setting on x4 in the BIOS?
https://imgur.com/8091jxz

ACPI\PNP0A0A is for Asus Hardware-Monitoring-Chips

Comment: Have you checked in the BIOS that x4 is not set as the speed? 
That would be the only thing I found in the manual that deactivates the ports for the sound card.

Comment: @Tekkie_Boy I just checked in the BIOS, unfortunately it is set to x2 :( Seems like the card needs to go back to Amazon

Answer (score 0):

That sound card really is a USB sound chip integrated with PCIe USB controller.

You need to install the drivers, first the drivers for the USB controller chip, and then drivers for the USB sound chip.

Comment: So you think that it actually sees the card but missing the USB controller driver (which means it can not see the sound card yet)?

Comment: If you have not installed the USB controller driver, the PC can't see anything except the USB controller.

Comment: it seems the driver I need is AsMedia USB 3.0 Controller Driver which I can not find anywhere online.

Comment: Why not go to manufacturer web page for the product and download drivers?

Comment: The manufactorer does not have a download section on the website but it turns out that Asus includes those drives inside a sub-folder in the audio card driver but I did not notice before.

Comment: I should have said sound card manufacturer, sorry. Yes they provide all the necessary drivers as they sell the sound card.